# Recursively extract rar files

Tags: command-line, bash, compression, extract, rar

Sometimes i download torrents from internet, no illegal stuff, just torrents.

The finished torrent is a directory, containing:

1. `file.rar`

And the `file.rar` "chunks"

2. `file.r00`
3. `file.r01`
4. `file.r02`
5. `file.r03`
6. `file.r04`
7. `file.r05`
8. `file.r06`
9. `file.r07`
10. `file.r08`
11. `file.r09`
12. `file.r10`
13. `file.r11`
14. `file.r12`
15. `file.r13`
16. `file.r14`
17. `file.r15`
18. `file.r16`
19. `file.r17`
20. `file.r18`
21. `file.r19`
22. `file.r20`
23. `file.r21`
24. `file.r22`
25. `file.r23`
26. `file.r24`
27. `file.r25`
28. `file.r26`
29. `file.r27`
30. `file.r28`
31. `file.r29`
32. `file.r30`
33. `file.r31`
34. `file.r32`
35. `file.r33`
36. `file.r34`
37. `file.r35`
38. `file.r36`
39. `file.r37`
40. `file.r38`
41. `file.r39`
42. `file.r40`
43. `file.r41`
44. `file.r42`
45. `file.r43`
46. `file.r44`
47. `file.r45`
48. `file.r46`
49. `file.r47`
50. `file.r48`
51. `file.r49`
    .... and so on

And when i unrar `file.rar`, it extracts `file.iso`. After that process im no longer in need of `file.rar` and `file.r[00..49]`. Sometimes there are hundreds of rar chunks, its dynamic.

An example:

In my home direcoty `~`, i have a `Downloads` folder that my downloaded torrents are stored in.

I cd in to the `Downloads` folder.
`$ cd Downloads/`

In `Downloads` folder there are multipel downloaded torrents all with a dynamic range of "chunks".

`Downloads ls`

```
Ubuntu/
Pop_Os/
Mint/
Kodachi/
```

From `Downloads` folder, i would like to run a command to extract all rar files in the subfolders, in this case: Ubuntu, Pop_Os, Mint and Kodachi. And in the same process remove `*.rar` and `*.r[00..**]`. `ubuntu.iso` is extracted in the subfolder "ubuntu", `pop_os.iso` is extracted in subfolder "Pop_Os" and so on.

Next month the downloads folder might contain:

```
Parrot_OS/
Manjaro/
Arch/
```

I dont want to have to change anything in the command i execute in `~/Downloads`.

Hope this clears some of the questions i have received in the comments.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What folder? `Holdiday_pictures_greece`? Are all the `rar` files in the same directory or can they also be in subdirectories? Does it work if you just replace `-exec` with `-execdir`?

Comment: May I ask why you think the tags [tag:rar], [tag:extract] irrelevant to the post?

Comment: You still haven't explained where the rar files are. You seem to be implying you have more than one dir of rar files, if so, please tell us. And we also need to know whether they will always be in the top level, whether you will always have `Holdiday_pictures_greece/file1.rar` or if you can also have `Holdiday_pictures_greece/subDir1/file1.rar`. Finally, I ask again, does it  work if you just replace `-exec` with `-execdir`?

Comment: @terdon The rar files is nested in subfolders yes, and no execdir doesn't work

Comment: @Adam yes, but are there sub-subfolders? Are all rar files in `Holiday_pictures_greece` (or Malta or whatever) or can you also have `Holiday_pictures_greece/subDir1/file1.rar`? And, if so, where should those be extracted? In `Holiday_pictures_greece` or in `Holiday_pictures_greece/subDir1`?

Comment: @terdon Yes their can be multipel subfolders, and all files should be extracted in the folder were the rar file is located. So `Holiday_pictures_greece/subDir1/file1.rar` should be extracted in `Holiday_pictures_greece/subDir1/`thanks

Comment: Then please [edit] all this information into your question.

Comment: @terdon It´s a very straight forward question. Find rar files recursively, extract them to the folder where they were found. The question is a wall of text now =)

Comment: No, it isn't straightforward at all, actually. For example, had you answered that you don't have multiple subfolders, the solution would have been much simpler with a shell loop instead of `find`.  Also, by the way, note that your `rm *.r*` will delete all files whose name includes `.r` not only `.rar` files. I suggest you use `rm *.rar` instead but that shouldn't even be necessary since you've already removed them using `find`.

Comment: @terdon i don't want to keep the `*.rar` files, nor the chunks of if `*.r01, *.r02, *.r03, *.r04` (hence @anwar redundant tags?) and so on. And I thought that `recursively` was a very good description that I want to execute a command in more than one folder.

Comment: Using the wildcard `*.r*` is dangerous in that context though - at very least it should be a specific one that says that the characters after 'r' are digits (otherwise, e.g. for photography purposes, you'll end up destroying anything that's saved as `.raw`).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably simpler to do with a `while` loop instead of `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        dir=$(dirname "$file")
        rar=$(basename "$file")
        cd "$dir"
        unrar e "$rar" && rm "$rar"
        cd -
    done
```

Comment: extracts all .rar's to the `pwd`

Comment: @srghma yes, exactly, that's what the question asked for.

Comment: I mean, yes, it should have extracted to `cd "$dir"` , but didnt work for me, instead extracted to dir where the `find` was run. Had to use the `unrar x` instead

Comment: Thanks! This answer extracts the files in the correct folder, removes the *.rar file but doesent remove the chunks `*.r01, *.r02, *.r03, *.r04`

Comment: @Adam that's probably why I asked you to edit your question so many times all those years ago (see the comments under your question), but you refused and insisted everything was clear and straightforward. Since you refused, I didn't have all the information I needed to be able to give you a better answer. Maybe you want something like `rm *.r0[0-9]` but I can't know with the information you have provided.

Comment: @terdon i will edit the initial question. happy new year!

Comment: @terdon I have read your previous comments and edited my question

Answer (score 0):

man unrar :

NON-FREE UNRAR COMPATIBLE SYNOPSIS
       unrar-free  [elvx]   [-ep]   [-o+]  [-o-]  [-ppassword]  [-u]  [--] AR‐
       CHIVE  [FILE ...]           [DESTINATION]

```
   This syntax should only be used in front-end programs which  are  using
   non-free  unrar as a back-end. It is recommended to use this program by
   GNU command line syntax.

   e         Extract files from archive without full path.

   l         List files in archive.

   v         Verbose list files in archive.
```

x : **Extract files from archive with full path**.

Answer (score 0):

will extract `.rar` to it's original folder, not to `pwd`

```
cd FOLDER_WITH_RAR
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      dir=$(dirname "$file")
      rar=$(basename "$file")
      cd "$dir"
      echo "file=$file, dir=$dir, rar=$rar"
      unrar x "$rar"
      # rm -f "$rar"
      cd -
    done
```

Comment: notice the other answer avoids calling   `rm -f xxx` which is a command which should be avoided ... delete your answer if appropriate as the other answer does the job already

Comment: @ScottStensland 1. commented 2. added comment to the other answer